# Pandas: None data returned with if and conditional apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply an .apply function that uses **if** with **and** logic per row to populate a column based on the values of two other columns.
In my dataset I've got two columns I want to check to see if the rows qualify before I apply the lookup I want. In my mapping data frame I've split it into 4 separate data frames.

```
1.price per node new - prod
2.price per node new - non prod
3.price per node expansion - prod
4.price per node expansion - non prod
```

**product_and_range_new_prod**

```
   product_and_range_p_n    score_p_n
0   Basic 3-4K             0.090909
1   Basic 5-6K             0.090909
2   Basic 6-7K             0.090909
```

**product_and_range_new_non_prod**

```
      product_and_range_np_n    score_np_n
0        Basic 3-4K               0.0
1        Basic 5-6K               0.0
2        Adv   1-2K               0.2
```

**product_and_range_expansion_prod**

```
     product_and_range_p_e  score_p_e
0        Basic 1-2K         0.230769  
1        Basic 3-4K         0.230769
2        Basic 5-6K         0.230769
```

**product_and_range_expansion_non_prod**

```
     product_and_range_np_e score_np_e
0        Basic 2-3K          0.00
1        Basic 5-6K          0.00
2        Adv 1-2K            0.25
```

**Main DF** aka df

```
    price_per_node  deal_type   product_group
0   NaN             Expansion   None
1   11823.517808    Expansion   Prod
2   6422.994411     New         Prod
3   14045.337803    Expansion   Prod
4   1495.890411     Expansion   Non-Prod
```

When I try to apply a function with some logic, If prod and new apply correct dataframe etc I'm getting none across all rows. Can someone please explain why I don't get any of my if statements applying the return data?

**Here's my function:**

```
def per_node_price_score(row):

    try:
        if row['deal_type'] == 'New' and row['product_group'] == 'Prod':

            return product_and_range_new_prod.loc[product_and_range_new_prod['product_and_range_p_n'] == row['price_per_node']].iloc[-1]['score_p_n']

        elif row['deal_type'] == 'New' and row['product_group'] == 'Non-Prod':

            return product_and_range_new_non_prod.loc[product_and_range_new_non_prod['product_and_range_np_n'] == row['price_per_node']].iloc[-1]['score_np_n']

        elif row['deal_type'] == 'Expansion' and row['product_group'] == 'Prod':

            return product_and_range_expansion_prod.loc[product_and_range_expansion_prod['product_and_range_p_e'] == row['price_per_node']].iloc[-1]['score_p_e']

        elif row['deal_type'] == 'Expansion' and row['product_group'] == 'Non-Prod':

            return product_and_range_expansion_non_prod.loc[product_and_range_expansion_non_prod['product_and_range_np_e'] == row['price_per_node']].iloc[-1]['score_np_e']

    except: IndexError

df['per_node_price_score'] = df.apply(per_node_price_score, axis=1)

df.head(5)
```

Comment: Hi, it is hard to say, what is going wrong, but what jumped into my eye directly was that your dataframes have regular int indexes and it seems to me, that these indexes are not alligned. please also add a description, of what your function should do and the sizes of your dataframes. Maybe there is another solution to solve this without using an apply function. See my posting below for a description of what I think why you don't get your intended result.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you have written shouldn't return a value as far as I can tell. You tell the function to return an index of `product_and_range_new_prod` when

```
product_and_range_new_prod['product_and_range_p_n'] == row['price_per_node']
```

but when does that happen? You need to organize your data a little differently. What you want is it to return the index when the price_per_node is within the range listed. First of all, the range should be separate from the basic/advanced information. Then, it probably makes sense to list range as two separate max and min columns, and then use greater than or less than logic to find the right index with product price

Also, it might be a good idea to combine your four DataFrames and use their descriptive titles as an extra column. In the end, if you follow all of this, your DataFrame would look like this

```
   product    min    max    score    type
0   Basic    3000    4000   0.090909 product_and_range_new_prod
1   Basic    5000    6000   0.090909 product_and_range_new_prod
2   Basic    6000    7000   0.090909 product_and_range_new_prod
3   Basic    3000    4000   0.0      product_and_range_new_non_prod
4   Basic    5000    6000   0.0      product_and_range_new_non_prod
5   Adv      1000    2000   0.2      product_and_range_new_non_prod
6   Basic    1000    2000   0.230769 product_and_range_expansion_prod  
7   Basic    3000    4000   0.230769 product_and_range_expansion_prod
8   Basic    5000    6000   0.230769 product_and_range_expansion_prod
9   Basic    2000    3000   0.00     product_and_range_expansion_non_prod
10  Basic    5000    6000   0.00     product_and_range_expansion_non_prod
11  Adv      1000    2000   0.25     product_and_range_expansion_non_prod
```

Another issue is that you reference other DataFrames in your function that are not passed along. You can add arguments to your apply function, as described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), but you will probably need to reference your variables differently.

For instance, if you pass along your arguments as kwargs (key word arguments), you will have to reference them as dictionary values. I wrote a trivial example below

```
def apply_function(row,**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['key1'])

df.apply(key1='some_variable')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to clarify something and explain, why I think your logic doesn't do, what you expect:

In your apply function you check `deal_type` and `prod_group`. In the very first `if`-clause, you return the value of an expression, that is equivalent to (just reformatted/assigned variables to see all at one glance):

```
value= row['price_per_node']
indexer= product_and_range_new_prod['product_and_range_p_n'] == value
product_and_range_new_prod.loc[indexer].iloc[-1]['score_p_n']
```

If I didn't miss something, `indexer` will be `False` for all rows, because `value` is a `float` value, while `product_and_range_new_prod['product_and_range_p_n']` is a string like `Basic 3-4K'` and so what you return will be nothing. You probably get an `IndexError` for all rows.

Did you maybe mean to "lookup" on another field or "lookup" based on the index?
The index above doesn't seem to be aligned for all the dataframes, or is it?

In both cases, I think you can do your "lookup" more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

### These conditions are never met:

```
[product_and_range_new_prod['product_and_range_p_n'] == row['price_per_node']
[product_and_range_new_non_prod['product_and_range_np_n'] == row['price_per_node']
[product_and_range_expansion_prod['product_and_range_p_e'] == row['price_per_node']
[product_and_range_expansion_non_prod['product_and_range_np_e'] == row['price_per_node']
```

### These are examples of what is being compared:

```
df.price_per_node
0             NaN
1    11823.517808
2     6422.994411
3    14045.337803
4     1495.890411
Name: price_per_node, dtype: float64

product_and_range_new_prod.product_and_range_p_n
0    Basic 3-4K
1    Basic 5-6K
2    Basic 6-7K
Name: product_and_range_p_n, dtype: object
```

### `if` - `elif` logic works without issue:

#### DataFrame (`df`)

[image]

#### Function

```
def per_node_price_score(row):

    try:
        if row['deal_type'] == 'New' and row['product_group'] == 'Prod':
            print('1')

        elif row['deal_type'] == 'New' and row['product_group'] == 'Non-Prod':
            print('2')

        elif row['deal_type'] == 'Expansion' and row['product_group'] == 'Prod':
            print('3')

        elif row['deal_type'] == 'Expansion' and row['product_group'] == 'Non-Prod':
            print('4')

    except: IndexError
```

#### Function Call

```
df['per_node_price_score'] = df.apply(per_node_price_score, axis=1)

>>> 3
    1
    3
    4
    2
```

- Given the function call, we can see from the output, that each `if / elif` condition is met